# mingw32-g++: 'std::tr1' has not been declared

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, codeblocks

I'm facing this issue using Code::Blocks 16.01, everything works perfectly in Visual Studio 2015. The compiler option "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]" is enabled, and the build log is:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -g  -c "<path>\heuristic.cpp" -o .objs\heuristic.o
In file included from <path>\METSlib\metslib-0.5.3\metslib\mets.hh:129:0,
                 from <path>\Model.h:2,
                 from <path>\<file>,
                 from <path>\<file>:
<path>\METSlib\metslib-0.5.3\metslib\model.hh: In function 'void mets::random_shuffle(mets::permutation_problem&, random_generator&)':
<path>\METSlib\metslib-0.5.3\metslib\model.hh:252:10: error: 'std::tr1' has not been declared
     std::tr1::uniform_int<size_t> unigen;
```

followed by lots of other errors, all related to the missing std::tr1 library. (I've replaced some paths and files with placeholders for privacy)

What am I missing in the compiler configuration?[image]

Comment: The compiler which comes with CB by default is pretty old. I suggest you to install a better compiler, something like latest MinGW-w64.

Comment: tr1 was a temporary thing before c++11.  Most thing in tr1 are now part of the standard so you can use std:: instead of std::tr1:: .

Comment: @brianbeuning I tried replacing all occurrences of `std::tr1::` with `std::` but the compiler still returned the same error: "'std::tr1' has not been declared".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've uninstalled CodeBlocks and its MinGW version, reinstalled CodeBlocks w/o MinGW and manually installed the latest version of MinGW. Still the same error, even trying replacing `std::tr1` with `std::`

Comment: @brianbeuning ok it seems that I needed to restard CodeBlocks to get an updated error message after removing `tr1::`. However, removing it doesn't seem to be a solution since I need to use `std::tr1::variate_generator` which wasn't moved to `std::`.

Comment: Try to enable `-std=c++0x` instead of `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat A library that I'm using, METSLib, required c++11 to work. However, in the end I ditched CodeBlocks for Visual Studio in order to avoid this problem.